# How to check if file exists in u-boot script?

Tags: android, linux, usb, u-boot

I would like, from my u-boot script, to check the existence of a file on a device before running the image on this device.
Indeed, this would ensure to have access to the requested device before booting from it.
How could I test the file existence using u-boot console commands?

The following test does a ls on the USB stick, and here are the results with USB stick present:

```
> if ext2ls usb 0; then echo "USB ON"; else echo "USB KO"; fi
    <DIR>       4096 .
    <DIR>       4096 ..
    <DIR>      16384 lost+found
    <DIR>       4096 boot
                4096 boot.scr
USB ON
```

Same test without USB stick:

```
> if ext2ls usb 0; then echo "USB ON"; else echo "USB KO"; fi
** Bad device usb 0 **
USB KO
```

My wish would be to test the presence of the boot.scr file in fact. How could I do that please?

Answer (score 7):

You're fairly close.  Since ext2ls (or the generic ls) only work on directories you instead need to do:

```
=> if load mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} notfound; then echo found; else echo notfound;fi
** File not found notfound **
=> if load mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} boot.scr; then echo found; else echo notfound;fi
27980 bytes read in 26 ms (1 MiB/s)
found
```

You can see more examples of this kind of test and fall back in include/config_distro_bootcmd.h

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but answering anyways since I was looking for this info.

As Tom said, there are indeed examples in `include/config_distro_bootcmd.h`.

The way to check if a file exists is using `test -e`. This works in `v2021.07` of u-boot.

Example: I have a `u-boot.scr` in the fat partition of my sdcard, which is the first partition. This is how I check if the file exists and then run it:

```sh
if test -e mmc 0:1 u-boot.scr; then fatload mmc 0:1 0x2000000 u-boot.scr; source 0x2000000; fi;
```

If you have the file in a subfolder, just reference it the same way: `scripts/u-boot.scr`.